# Reversing all nested sequences

Tags: recursion, comparative-review, clojure

I'm writing a function that returns all (nested) sequences reversed:

```
(defn my-reverse-v1 [input]
  (let [head (first input)
        tail (rest input)]
    (if head
      (conj (my-reverse-v1 (vec tail))
            (if (sequential? head)
              (my-reverse-v1 (vec head))
              head))
      [])))

(defn my-reverse-v2 [initial input]
  (let [head (first input)
        tail (rest input)]
    (if head
      (recur (cons (if (sequential? head) (my-reverse-v2 [] head) head) initial) tail)
      (vec initial))))

(defn test-my-reverse []
  (let [input [[1 2] 3 [4 [5 6]] 7 [8 [9 [10 11] 12]]]
        expected [[[12 [11 10] 9] 8] 7 [[6 5] 4] 3 [2 1]]]
    (println "my-reverse-v1:" (= expected (my-reverse-v1 input)))
    (println "my-reverse-v2:" (= expected (my-reverse-v2 [] input)))))
```

`my-reverse-v2` is the tail-recursive version, whereas `my-reverse-v1` isn't. These two functions work as expected, but I think there will be lots more succinct or Clojure-ish implementations for the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an extremely short version of the (not tail-) recursive algorithm, I recommend using [walk](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/walk). You can write the code with `walk` like this:

```
(defn my-reverse-v3 [input]
  (walk #(if (sequential? %) (my-reverse-v3 %) %) reverse input))
```

For a properly tail-recursive version, my cleanest results use [clojure.zip](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip):

```
(defn my-reverse-v4 [input]
  (loop [z-input
         (zipper sequential? seq (fn [_ c] c) input)]
    (if (end? z-input)
      (root z-input)
      (recur (next (edit z-input #(if (sequential? %) (reverse %) %)))))))
```

For this solution, I followed a structure which I found at [Exploration through Example](http://www.exampler.com/blog/2010/09/01/editing-trees-in-clojure-with-clojurezip).

(Incidentally, your `my-reverse-v2` is *not* tail-recursive. The function calls itself within a call to `cons`. One of the nice things about Clojure's `recur` is that it will throw a compile error when it's not used in a tail-recursive position; you'd surely see that in action here.)